# Botão de fechar no <md-select>

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Galera estou usando o angular material, e preciso de um botão de fechar quando faço a seleção do select, ele só fecha o box se clicar fora, abaixo tem um exemplo:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" layout layout-align="center center">
    <md-select ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Escolha" ng-change="onChange()" md-on-open="onOpen()">
        <md-option value="0">Opção A</md-option>
        <md-option value="1">Opção B</md-option>
        <button>fechar (x)</buton>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.onChange = function() {
        //alert('on change');
    };

    $scope.onOpen = function() {
        //alert('on open');
    };
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/samucsouza/0bsgpe1n/5/

---

Fiz dessa forma, mas não deu certo:

```
 <md-button ng-click="fechar()">Botão fechar select</md-button>


    $scope.fechar = function () {
      $mdSelect.hide();
    };
```

> ```
> ReferenceError: $mdSelect is not defined
> ```

Comment: Olá Samuel!  Poderia incluir o código aqui na pergunta? Além de facilitar quem irá lhe ajudar, sua pergunta se adequa as regras do SO! Qualquer dúvida, de uma olhada em na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) ! Abraços!

Comment: Adicionei a resposta para o erro "ReferenceError: $mdSelect is not defined" na minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione um `ng-click` no botão com o seguinte código:

```
$mdSelect.hide();
```

**EDIT 1**

Você deve injetar a dependência do $mdSelect na declaração do controller:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSelect) {
  $scope.fechar = function() {
    $mdSelect.hide();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `ng-click` apenas negando a condição dele no click, e usar o `ng-show`, ou `ng-hide`, como preferir:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.display_box = true;
}
```

Só isso deve funcionar:

```
 <button ng-click="display_box=!display_box;"
         ng-class="{active:display_box=!display_box}">fechar (x)
 </buton>
 <md-select ng-show="display_box" ng-model="myModel...>
   conteúdo que irá ser escondido
 </md-select>
```